# How to convert href in Apple Push Notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am sending

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

in my payload. I want before an notification arrives i get the text of payload so that i convert that html to string to only show "Google". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, as the notification that is displayed on the lock screen is not handled by the App.

That being sad: you could of course add custom information to the payload, where your title/body just contains "Google" and the custom payload the full information that you would like to handle when your app is launched from the notification.